# Maven Deploy Command skips Deployment Silently

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a typical java project and I try to upload it to nexus with `mvn deploy` command.

When I run it with `mvn -X clean deploy -Dmaven.deploy.skip=false`, it shows in log:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@65c33b92
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = true
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Skipping artifact deployment
```

and that's all. How can it be possible? Is there any suggestion?

Note: there isn't extra configuration in `pom.xml` and I try to run it with Jenkins pipeline:

```
    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn -X clean deploy -Dmaven.deploy.skip=false'
        }
    }
```

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: The default value IS `false`, so not clear why you explicitly state it. Also, `mvn deploy:help -Ddetail=true` indicates the property is `maven.deploy.file.skip`, but `mvn deploy:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=deploy` indicates the property is `maven.deploy.skip`, so something odd. In either case, the default is `false`, so should not need to be specified.

Comment: BTW, it works on local but it doesn't work on Jenkins.

Comment: @IanW There are the goals `deploy` and `deploy-file` which use different parameters to skip. But as @Sha uses the `deploy` goal, this `maven-deploy.skip` argument should be correct. However, the plugin says `skip = true` in the debugging output. So it seems Jenkins doesn't pass on the parameter to the build process, or at least not correctly. Maybe try moving the argument before `clean deploy` makes a difference. IMHO the problem lies somewhere in the jenkins configuration and not on the maven side.

Comment: @MartinHöller exactly, the problem is on Jenkins-side. I'll try to solve it via custom deploy-file command. Maybe you can help how I can use deploy-file command for multi-module project. Our multi-module maven project like: https://github.com/senolatac/hexagonal-architecture-demo

Comment: You could always invoke a Jenkins maven step `mvn help:effective-settings` or `mvn help:effective-pom`. It won't actually help you trace where it's picking it up, but it it should show settings similar to your answer. If it doesn't, then it's definitely set somewhere / somehow. The [effective settings](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) override order is Default -> Global; ( `$M2_HOME/conf`) -> User (`~/.m2/`) -> Project (nearest `pom.xml` -> Environment (ie: command line: `ie: mvn -Dparameter=value`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. When I check parent pom file, I found a script like:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But it is strange, it works on local properly even with this config.